# Show pre-load image during images load but all images are different size

Tags: jquery, preloader, preloading, image-preloader

I want to display pre-load image center of image's div. But all images have different size so pre-load image can not be displayed in center of each image.

Thanks for advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use css to resolve this problem. Add class "pre-loader" to every image on your page, and describe it with css:

```
.pre-loader {
  background: #ccc url(loaderimageurl) center center no-repeat;
}
```

Then use js like this:

```
$("img").load(function () { $(this).removeClass("pre-loader"); });
```

Comment: to the best i recommend you to and `min-width` and `min-height` to every image

Comment: it can ruin the makeup. and small images will be loaded quick enough. i guess. imo thats bad idea to put loaders on images.

Comment: I tried your offer. load image can not be displayed if width and heigh is not determined. when I determine width and height and when I addClass to all images, all of these image resized to load image.

Comment: You can determine those parameters in css-rule for .pre-loader, like np.